# Can I fix corrupted firmware on a HP Color laserjet CM1312 mfp?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, firmware, hp-laserjet

During a firmware update which was interupted I now get the message:-"firmware corrupted ready 2 download" on HP Color laserjet CM1312 mfp, I`ve tried to re-install the firmware but it only gets as far "downloading" which then stops with message "fatal error 2! call HP support".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can I would imagine if it is like any other device.

How was it interrupted when updating? If a firmware update gets to a certain point and fail it can leave the device with no software at all. Meaning you now own  a HP brick.

Give HP a call them might offer further support.